# org.bitcoinj.core.AddressFormatException: Illegal character 0 at position 0 when converting 66 characters long private key to ECKey

Tags: bitcoin, private-key, java-security, bitcoinj

I have a `bitcoin` private key which is 66 characters long, including a `0x` prefix and I need to convert it to a `ECKey`. I tried this:

```
String private = "0x..."; // 66 characters total
DumpedPrivateKey dpk = DumpedPrivateKey.fromBase58(null, wif);
ECKey key = dpk.getKey();
```

it throws

```
org.bitcoinj.core.AddressFormatException: Illegal character 0 at position 0
```

If I remove the `0x` the same error is thrown for any other `0` in the `private` string.

The 66 characters long key is something that comes from outside of our system, so out of my control. What am I missing here? How do I convert it so I could use the `ECKey` to sign transactions?

Comment: It looks like it is expecting the key in base58, which does not include the `0` character. It seems to be expecting wallet import format keys instead. Either convert your hex key to a WIF one, or use a method to import it from hex if available

Comment: @RaghavSood thanks. How do I convert the key to WIF?

Answer (score -1):

Importing it from hex(Byte Array) will solve the problem. See the code below

```
ECKey key = ECKey.fromPrivate(privateKeyByteArrayHere);
```

Do not include preceding 80 and post fixing 01/Checksum to the byte array(byte[ ]).